# Error in creating Tkinter GUI: 'Window' object has no attribute '_tk'

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a weather app using Python 3.5, Tkinter, and the Weather Underground API. I am trying to put in an `Entry` widget where the user can enter in a location. I'm making it so that when the user hits enter, it will display the temperature and the current conditions for the location entered. Here is my code that is supposed to create the GUI window:

```
import json, requests, re
from tkinter import *

class Window:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry("300x100")

        self.place = StringVar
        instructions = Label(self.root, text="Enter in city (City, State/Country) or zipcode.")
        self.locationEntry = Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.place)

        instructions.pack()
        self.locationEntry.bind("<Return>", self.onEnter())
        self.locationEntry.pack()

        self.root.mainloop()

    def onEnter(self):
        self.place = self.place.get(self)

Window()
```

When I run the program, no window comes up and I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/jsorh/OneDrive/Documents/School/Web Design/weather/App/WeatherApp.py", line 70, in <module>
    Window()   File "C:/Users/jsorh/OneDrive/Documents/School/Web Design/weather/App/WeatherApp.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.locationEntry.bind("<Return>", self.onEnter())   File "C:/Users/jsorh/OneDrive/Documents/School/Web Design/weather/App/WeatherApp.py", line 26, in onEnter
    self.place = self.place.get(self)   File "C:\Users\jsorh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 333, in get
    value = self._tk.globalgetvar(self._name) AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute '_tk'
```

I've looked around the internet for some solutions, but I can't really understand how to fix this. I'm a beginner at programming, so please explain things as simply as possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code there are the following errors:

- You must be change `StringVar` to `StringVar()` since you are creating an object.
- You must be change `self.locationEntry.bind("<Return>", self.onEnter())` to `self.locationEntry.bind("<Return>", self.onEnter)` because the function asks you for the name of the callback
- You must be change `def onEnter(self):` to `def onEnter(self, event):` because the callback function receives the event information in that new variable.
- You must be change`self.place.get(self)` to `self.place.get()` because the `get()` function does not need parameters.
- You must be change `self.place` to `place` or another variable, since this already exists.

**Code corrected:**

```
import json, requests, re
from tkinter import *

class Window:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry("300x100")

        self.place = StringVar()
        instructions = Label(self.root, text="Enter in city (City, State/Country) or zipcode.")
        self.locationEntry = Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.place)

        instructions.pack()
        self.locationEntry.bind("<Return>", self.onEnter)
        self.locationEntry.pack()

        self.root.mainloop()

    def onEnter(self, event):
        place = self.place.get()
        print(place)

Window()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
import codecs
import urllib , cStringIO
import string
from Tkinter import *

weather_api =urllib.urlopen('https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22nagercoil%2C%20IND%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys')
weather_json = json.load(weather_api)
data_location = weather_json["query"]['results']['channel']['location']
place = data_location['city']

data_item = weather_json["query"]['results']['channel']['item']
fore_cast = data_item['forecast'][0]['text']
temp = data_item['condition']['temp']
date = data_item['condition']['date']
data_image= weather_json["query"]['results']['channel']['image']
root = Tk()
f = Frame(width=800, height=546, bg='green', colormap='new')

#p = PhotoImage(file=urlopen(file))
##ph =Label(root ,image=p)
w0 = Label(root, fg='#FF6699', text=fore_cast, font=("Helvetica",15))
w = Label(root, fg='blue', text=temp + u'\N{DEGREE SIGN}'+'F', font=("Helvetica",56))
w1 = Label(root, fg='#3399CC', text=place, font=("Helvetica",15))
w0.pack()
w.pack()
w1.pack()
##ph.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

this code might use full for you